# Cleanup when using controller as

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an angular application and come to fancy the "controller as" syntax. What I like with the "controller as" syntax is that I don't have to inject the $scope but I don't see any way to know when to run cleanup code without the $destroy event. However, in some places I need to do some cleanup when the controllers scope is removed. If you inject the $scope it wouldn't be a problem since a $destroy is triggered when the scope is removed but I would like to avoid injecting the scope as long as possible.

Is it possible to register some kind of listener for when a controller is removed when you use the "controller as" syntax whitout injecting the $scope?

Here is an example of what I would like to cleanup. I have a message bus where I can register new listeners for some event. When the controller is removed, I would like to unregister from the messagebus.

```
   controller('myController', function (messageBus) {
       var vm = this;
       vm.onNewMessage = function (message) {
           console.log(message);
       };
       messageBus.on('NEW_MESSAGE', vm.onNewMessage);

       //messageBus.off() - Don't know when to run this
   });
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide an example of exactly what kind of cleanup you are needing to do.

Comment: You need to inject $scope. I still prefer it this way. Think of $scope as your class variable and vm as your instance variable. That's not actually what they are, but it helps when determining which to use. Just use vm everywhere, and $scope for $on, $destroy, $broadcast.